# flutter filterchip ( single choice )

Tags: flutter, filter

I have filterchip
its work fine

but I need users to choose single choice

so other chips will not check

to make users choose one value

if filterchip have to choose one or should use something else

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: cityCategory
                      .map((city) => Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: screenWidth * 0.05),
                            child: FilterChip(
                                side: BorderSide(
                                    width: 2, color: ColorApp.light.get()),
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                checkmarkColor: Colors.white,
                                selectedColor: ColorApp.dark.get(),
                                labelStyle: GoogleFonts.elMessiri(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                backgroundColor: ColorApp.middle.get(),
                                shadowColor: ColorApp.dark.get(),
                                elevation: 5,
                                label: Text(
                                  city,
                                ),
                                selected: selectedCityCategory.contains(city),
                                onSelected: (selected) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (selected) {
                                      selectedCityCategory.add(city);
                                    } else {
                                      selectedCityCategory.remove(city);
                                    }
                                  });
                                }),
                          ))
                      .toList()),
```

Comment: i just edited my answer with example code and output

Answer (score 0):

make your selectedCityCategory to String if city is String or make the same datatype as city

added modified code below hope this will solve your problem
[image]

```
final cityCategory = [
  'NewYork',
  'London',
  'Toronto',
  'Vegas',
  'Tokyo',
  'Delhi'
];
var selectedCityCategory = "";

class ChipSelectionDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChipSelectionDemo({super.key});

  @override
  State<ChipSelectionDemo> createState() => _ChipSelectionDemoState();
}

class _ChipSelectionDemoState extends State<ChipSelectionDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: cityCategory
                  .map((city) => Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: FilterChip(
                            side: BorderSide(
                              width: 2,
                            ),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            checkmarkColor: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 5,
                            label: Text(
                              city,
                            ),
                            selected: selectedCityCategory == city,
                            onSelected: (selected) {
                              setState(() {
                                selectedCityCategory = city;
                              });
                            }),
                      ))
                  .toList()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```